# Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to integrate firebase phone OTP verification in my flutter app. Now, when a button is clicked, I am getting this error:

```
ForceRecaptchaFlow from phoneAuthOptions = false, ForceRecaptchaFlow from firebaseSettings = false
W/System  ( 4367): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/TrafficStats( 4367): tagSocket(73) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
I/PlayCore( 4367): UID: [10162]  PID: [4367] IntegrityService : requestIntegrityToken(IntegrityTokenRequest{nonce=DZbwPB95mzwtBbgqcpPKnQqBoNSKj0zFgVVgh1fvBG0, cloudProjectNumber=551503664846})
I/PlayCore( 4367): UID: [10162]  PID: [4367] IntegrityService : Initiate binding to the service.
I/PlayCore( 4367): UID: [10162]  PID: [4367] IntegrityService : Failed to bind to the service.
E/zzb     ( 4367): Play Integrity Token fetch failed, falling back to Recaptcha-9: Integrity API error (-9): Binding to the service in the Play Store has failed. This can be due to having an old Play Store version installed on the device.
E/zzb     ( 4367): Ask the user to update Play Store.
E/zzb     ( 4367):  (https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/reference/com/google/android/play/core/integrity/model/IntegrityErrorCode.html#CANNOT_BIND_TO_SERVICE).
D/EGL_emulation( 4367): app_time_stats: avg=41.80ms min=3.95ms max=507.57ms count=23
W/System  ( 4367): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/Parcel  ( 4367): Expecting binder but got null!
E/FirebaseAuth( 4367): [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
E/zzb     ( 4367): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification
W/System  ( 4367): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/FirebaseAuth( 4367): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
D/FirebaseAuth( 4367): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +917977501362, error - This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
```

Also, I have added the sha-1 and sha-256 to the firebase console. Still the error doesn't go away.

Phone sign in is also activated on firebase console.

Comment: is this problem is limited to one device or on other device also ? ,other then that consider updating the play store on that device .

Comment: The problem is on all the devices @Rainysidewalks

Comment: try by adding the sha keys again.and see?